# Async/Await with Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Im trying fetch all tickets from all users collection from `firestore` and i using this function

```js
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();

const GetAllUsersTickets = async () => {
    const usersRef = await firestore.collection('users').get();
    const usersTicketsRef = await usersRef.docs.map(user => user.ref.collection('tickets'));
    const tickets = await usersTicketsRef.map(el => el.get())
    tickets.map(ticket => ticket.then(snap => snap.docs.map(el => console.log(el.data()))))
}
```

Is there another method to get the data that is returned by the `promise` instead using `then`?

Comment: `map()` doesn't return a promise, so it doesn't make sense to await it.  The only thing here that's await-able are the individual calls to `get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I would write the code as:

```
 const GetAllUsersTickets = async () => {
    //the .get() is asynchronous
    const usersRef = await firestore.collection('users').get();

    //the below just creates an array of references to ticket COLLECTIONS for each user
    //it's synchronous; no need for await
    const usersTicketsRef = usersRef.docs.map(user => user.ref.collection('tickets'));

    //the following .get()'s ARE asynchronous, but .map() isn't -
    // so we need Promise.All() - the .then() hack attempts to wait for each, but the 
    // promise.all is a little clearer
    const tickets = await Promise.all(usersTicketsRef.map(el => el.get()));

    //at this point, tickets is an array of snapshots, so the following is synchronous
    tickets.map(ticket => (snap => snap.docs.map(el => console.log(el.data()))))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a for-of loop

The for-of loop supports waiting for asynchronous calls or actions using await.

```
const usersRef = await firestore.collection('users').get();
const usersTicketsRef = usersRef.docs.map(user => user.ref.collection('tickets'));

for (const ticketRef of usersTicketsRef) {
  const ticket = await ticketRef.get();

  console.log(ticket.data());
}
```

It can be a nice way to get past using `.then()`, when you need to loop over all items anyway as described in your case.

#### Improve datastructure

Please note that if you're hitting the database very often, you might wanna create a more effective query, or structure your data in a more denormalised way.